# Update partial data in a excel sheet with a dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I've been trying to update a sheet (sheet1 in this case) of an excel file with a dataframe. I was able to do it by iterating over each cell but I want to check if there's any better way to do it..Say insert the whole dataframe at a single go.

The dataframe headers are same as the partial excel I'm trying to update. The below code runs without any error but it doesn't update my data or creates a completely new sheet with name 'Sheet1'.

Appreciate the help

```
data = {'id':['1', '2', '3'], 'name':[Jake,Long,Beth],'Rank':[3,3,3]} 


df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
workbook2 = openpyxl.load_workbook(path_of_excel_to_be_updated)

writer1 = pd.ExcelWriter(path_of_excel_to_be_updated,engine='openpyxl') 
writer1.book = workbook2 
df_test.to_excel(writer1,sheet_name='sheet1',index=False,startrow=0,
                 startcol=0,engine='openpyxl')



writer1.save()
writer1.close()
```